# Convert 3D model (obj or gltf) to < div's> and CSS

Tags: html, css, 3d, .obj, gltf

Is there any possibility to convert 3D element (obj or gltf details and relevant nodal coordinates) into HTML < div's> and CSS to recreate the same object.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't really possible. HTML and CSS are not designed to represent 3D geometries. Some clever things are possible with [ascii art](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=ascii#webgl_effects_ascii) (for a very simplified style) or [CSS box shadow](https://a.singlediv.com/) (which is hard work, and not automatic).

ThreeJS has a [CSS3DRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/renderers/CSS3DRenderer), but per its documentation, it doesn't support normal materials or geometry — it's used to position normal HTML elements within a 3D projection, for overlays and annotations.

Comment: Hey Don thank's for answering the question. Recently I was discovered tridiv.com, a Julian Garnier project. Tridiv is a web-based editor for creating 3D shapes in CSS. So I was thinking that maybe is possible to assign values with js from nodal coordinates to a CSS transform property.

Comment: Perhaps, but doing that for an arbitrary model is much harder than the simple shapes that tridiv.com supports. Some features a model might have (textures wrapping, skinning) simply won't work in CSS. If you are OK with those limitations and using SVG, [SVGRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/renderers/SVGRenderer) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this;

https://github.com/lucascassiano/cinema4d-3divs

Cinema4D(Python) Script to export 3D planes as 3D React Components

with some changes it could work.